# "Sneak peek on" vs. "sneak peek at"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

I would like to post a screenshot of my upcoming app. What is correct to say, "sneak peek on" or "sneak peek at"?

> - Here is a sneak peek *on* my app for iPhone.
> - Here is a sneak peek *at* my app for iPhone.

Comment: In the spirit of _Teach a man to fish..._, I'll say this: Once you learn how to use [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sneak+peak+on%2Csneak+peak+at&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), you won't need to ask a question like this one quite so often. Also, you should check out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) where a question about "which preposition is more appropriate" is more likely to be well-received.

Comment: @JR ngrams for preposition use? To catch a mouse? But yes, ELL is here for the beginners.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some info from the Oxford online dict:

> [*Sneak*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sneak?q=sneak): adjective [attributive] acting or done surreptitiously, unofficially, or without warning:
>   [*Peek*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peek?q=peek): noun
>   a quick or furtive look:
>   she sneaked a peek at the map

So, since its a look, I would recommend using *'at'* with it rather than *'on'*.
And also, googling around is always a good idea to find ans. We really learn a lot. And for your app sentence, you'd want to use *of* as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using *of*:

> - Here is a photograph of my dog.
> - Here is a sneak peak **of** my iPhone application.